# C# to Java: Base64String, MemoryStream, GZipStream

Tags: c#, java, memorystream, gzipstream, gzipinputstream

I have a Base64 string that's been gzipped in .NET and I would like to convert it back into a string in Java. I'm looking for some Java equivalents to the C# syntax, particularly:

- Convert.FromBase64String
- MemoryStream
- GZipStream

Here's the method I'd like to convert:

```
public static string Decompress(string zipText) {
    byte[] gzipBuff = Convert.FromBase64String(zipText);

    using (MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int msgLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(gzipBuff, 0);
        memstream.Write(gzipBuff, 4, gzipBuff.Length - 4);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[msgLength];

        memstream.Position = 0;
        using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(memstream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            gzip.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
     }
}
```

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Just a side note, does that C# code work OK ? Because you are allocating a buffer size with the length of the *compressed* GZip data, and then you are reading the *uncompressed* data to that same buffer.

Comment: The C# code above does work fine for decompressing. Thanks for your help on this one much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Base64, you have the `Base64` [class](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) from Apache Commons, and the `decodeBase64` method which takes a `String` and returns a `byte[]`.

Then, you can read the resulting `byte[]` into a [`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html). At last, pass the `ByteArrayInputStream` to a [GZipInputStream](http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html) and read the uncompressed bytes.

---

The code looks like something along these lines:

```
public static String Decompress(String zipText) throws IOException {
    byte[] gzipBuff = Base64.decodeBase64(zipText);

    ByteArrayInputStream memstream = new ByteArrayInputStream(gzipBuff);
    GZIPInputStream gzin = new GZIPInputStream(memstream);

    final int buffSize = 8192;
    byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[buffSize ];
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ((size = gzin.read(tempBuffer, 0, buffSize)) != -1) {
        baos.write(tempBuffer, 0, size);
    }        
    byte[] buffer = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();

    return new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
}
```

I didn't test the code, but I think it should work, maybe with a few modifications.

Answer (score 1):

For Base64, I recommend [iHolder's implementation](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/).

[GZipinputStream](http://www.ermalaev.spb.ru/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html) is what you need to decompress a GZip byte array.

ByteArrayOutputStream is what you use to write out bytes to memory. You then get the bytes and pass them to the constructor of a string object to convert them, preferably specifying the encoding.